# Updating Google spreadheets scripts automatically

Tags: google-apps-script

Is there a way for a google spreadsheet to fetch and copy the scripts from a different spreadsheet?

I have a file that users make an individual version for them to use. The file also includes various scripts, including one that updates the sheets and formulas in case the master file changes.

However, I haven't found any way in which to update the scripts themselves. I can't deploy the script as an add-on because that function is blocked in my company.

Is there any other way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to copy/update scripts in a sheet you can try using the [Apps Script API](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/concepts/).